# UITapGestureRecognizer not recognized because view is nested in multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom view that I present by tapping on either a button on the view controller or by tapping on a button on tableview cell (table view is a child of the view controller)

To dismiss the custom view I want the user to be able to tap anywhere on the screen to dismiss it. However due to the many hierarchies of the view in view controllers. A simple UITapGuestureRecognizer isn't working. Is there any workaround for a case like this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `UIView`, call it `MyTapView`. Assign this class your parent view, which holds all your subviews.
Override in your class the following to intercept any touches made to your `view` instance.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    // use this to pass the 'touch' onward in case no subviews trigger the touch
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01. This method does not take the view’s content into account when determining a hit (feel free to modify this). Thus, a view can still be returned even if the specified point is in a transparent portion of that view’s content and now, after it has been overridden, receives touches outside the bounds.